# Calling procedure in function

Tags: oracle, plsql

Can you call a PL/SQL procedure from inside a function?

I haven't come across with the practical example.So if anyone has come across with this please share.

Comment: *"However, I have made a very simple code"....* - Neither do we see any procedure in your question nor a function. Please note that this site is not for "sharing examples". You should post your coding attempt and problem statement to get help for things that are not working.

Comment: @KaushikNayak... I just mentioned that I have made and also I have a problem becuase I not getting the real scenario of calling procedure in function so that's the reason I have asked the question.And if you want the code that I attempt I can give you.

Comment: Just a tip: This is "code" site

Comment: @t.s. actually it's a site about programming...this question could definitely be answered, it wasn't an opinion question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can call any pl/sql program from inside any other pl/sql program. A function can call a function, a procedure can call a procedure which calls a function, a function can invoke a TYPE BODY...do an INSERT..which causes a TRIGGER to fire.

A simple (not really practical) example.

Using the HR schema where you have an EMPLOYEES table which includes columns EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, and LAST_NAME.

I have a function that takes in an INTEGER which we use to look up an EMPLOYEE record. We take their first and last names, and concat them together, and return the value back in UPPERCASE text.

Before we do that however, we call a procedure which does nothing but take a 5 second nap using the DBMS_LOCK package.

The code:

```
create or replace procedure do_nothing_comments (x in integer, y in integer)
is
begin
 null;
 -- yeah, this is a dumb demo
 dbms_lock.sleep(5);
end;
/

create or replace FUNCTION upper_name (
    x IN INTEGER
) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    upper_first_and_last VARCHAR2 (256);
BEGIN
    SELECT upper (first_name)
           || ' '
           || upper (last_name)
      INTO upper_first_and_last
      FROM employees
     WHERE employee_id = x;

    do_nothing_comments (1, 2); -- here we are calling the procedure
    RETURN upper_first_and_last;
END;
```

/

Now let's invoke the function.

```
DECLARE
  X NUMBER;
  v_Return VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  X := 101;

  v_Return := UPPER_NAME(
    X => X
  );
  :v_Return := v_Return;
END;
```

/

I'm going to do this in SQL Developer using the Execute feature with the function open:

[image]

I get the answer back...it just takes 5 seconds longer than it really needed to.

Comment: thank you for sharing the example...what will be the use of two parameters in the procedure as you have mentioned null and use the DBMS.sleep package. We can simply call the procedure in function without using any parameters.

Comment: @JaspreetSingh i had them in there as placeholders, they have no use, as does the procedure, i could have simply called dbms_lock.sleep(5) in the main function block...so this is a function that calls a procedure that calls a function

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
create or replace function demo
    return varchar2
as
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('Hello');
    return 1;
end demo;
```